# Lodash Filter Array and Get Parent Index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lodash

My Api returns this in json format

```
[
   {
      "title":"Category One",
      "data":[
         {
            "id":"5",
            "code":"0001",
            "name":"Item Name"
         },
         {
            "id":"6",
            "code":"0002",
            "name":"Item Name 2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Category Two",
      "data":[
         {
            "id":"7",
            "code":"0003",
            "name":"Item Name 3"
         },
         {
            "id":"8",
            "code":"0004",
            "name":"Item Name 4"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to filter above given array by id
I tried it like:

```
_.filter(data, ["title.data.id", "5"]);
```

But returns empty array, then i also tried it like:

```
_.filter(data, { data: [{ id: "5" }] });
```

But returns the full array.

Kindly guide what am i missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let obj = [
    {
        "title": "Category One",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "5",
                "code": "0001",
                "name": "Item Name"
            },
            {
                "id": "6",
                "code": "0002",
                "name": "Item Name 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Category Two",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "7",
                "code": "0003",
                "name": "Item Name 3"
            },
            {
                "id": "8",
                "code": "0004",
                "name": "Item Name 4"
            }
        ]
    }
]

function getFilterResult(filterValue) {
    let result = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        let data = obj[i]['data']
        let index = data.findIndex(da => da.id === filterValue)
        if (index > -1) {
            result['title'] = obj[i].title
            data[index]['name']="New Item" /* added the code for updating the Name filed */
            result['data'] = [data[index]]
        }
    }
    return result
}

let finalResult = getFilterResult("7")
console.log(finalResult)
```

Using lodash

```js
let data = [
    {
        "title": "Category One",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "5",
                "code": "0001",
                "name": "Item Name"
            },
            {
                "id": "6",
                "code": "0002",
                "name": "Item Name 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Category Two",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "7",
                "code": "0003",
                "name": "Item Name 3"
            },
            {
                "id": "8",
                "code": "0004",
                "name": "Item Name 4"
            }
        ]
    }
];

var output = _.find(data, item => _.find(item.data, d => d.id === '7'));
output['data'][_.findIndex(output['data'], { id: '7' })]['name']= "New Item";
console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not Working. It return full array

Comment: please check now i have edited my answer @DIGITALJEDI

Comment: Thanks it works but can you also do it with lodash?

Comment: Can i change the name after finding the index, using above method?

Comment: you can change the name using above method, @DIGITALJEDI if my answer solve your problem please mark it as correct

Comment: Can you update the code too, where i pass id and update the name and it returns the whole array.

Comment: I have updated the above method please check it @DIGITALJEDI

Comment: Thanks bro. I updated your answer as correct. One more thing can you do that in lodash too

Comment: Also one more thing its not returning the full object its just returning the filtered array only

Comment: so you only need to update the name field and send the full object ?

Comment: i have updated my the first solutrion will update the key and only send the match id object and second using lodash will return the full object with updated name filed @DIGITALJEDI

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the wanted properties and iterate the inner array as well.

```js
var data = [{ title: "Category One", data: [{ id: "5", code: "0001", name: "Item Name" }, { id: "6", code: "0002", name: "Item Name 2" }] }, { title: "Category Two", data: [{ id: "7", code: "0003", name: "Item Name 3" }, { id: "8", code: "0004", name: "Item Name 4" }] }],
    result = _.filter(data, ({ data }) => _.some(data, ({ id }) => id === "5"));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution with just simple JS

```js
const data = [
   {
      "title":"Category One",
      "data":[
         {
            "id":"5",
            "code":"0001",
            "name":"Item Name"
         },
         {
            "id":"6",
            "code":"0002",
            "name":"Item Name 2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Category Two",
      "data":[
         {
            "id":"7",
            "code":"0003",
            "name":"Item Name 3"
         },
         {
            "id":"8",
            "code":"0004",
            "name":"Item Name 4"
         }
      ]
   }
];

const requried = data.find(item => item.data.find(d => d.id === '5'));

console.log(requried);
```

Using lodash

```js
const data = [
   {
      "title":"Category One",
      "data":[
         {
            "id":"5",
            "code":"0001",
            "name":"Item Name"
         },
         {
            "id":"6",
            "code":"0002",
            "name":"Item Name 2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Category Two",
      "data":[
         {
            "id":"7",
            "code":"0003",
            "name":"Item Name 3"
         },
         {
            "id":"8",
            "code":"0004",
            "name":"Item Name 4"
         }
      ]
   }
];

const required = _.find(data, item => _.find(item.data, d => d.id === '5'));

console.log(required);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not working, return the both arrays from Category One dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reduce and filter

```js
const data = [
  {
    title: 'Category One',
    data: [
      {
        id: '5',
        code: '0001',
        name: 'Item Name',
      },
      {
        id: '6',
        code: '0002',
        name: 'Item Name 2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Category Two',
    data: [
      {
        id: '7',
        code: '0003',
        name: 'Item Name 3',
      },
      {
        id: '8',
        code: '0004',
        name: 'Item Name 4',
      },
    ],
  },
];

data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const val = curr.data.filter((d) => d.id == '5');
  if (val.length) acc = [...acc, ...val];

  return acc;
}, []);
```